# Reload parsedurl without having to close the app in Swift

Tags: json, swift, avplayer, reload, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerViewController that shows multiple short mp4 videoclips one after the other.

My only problem is: when i add new url's to my json file, i would need to close the app and open it to see the new video i added.

Is there a way that the parsedurl can be refreshed/reloaded perhaps every 10 minutes? In this case when new url's are added to the json file it will pull that information and add the new video to the end of the array, without having to close the app every time.

I was thinking of using the **timer.scheduledTimer**, is that possible? If so, how? And what is a better way to fix this?

**EDIT:**
Apparently my question is not very clear (my apologies).

I have this url:

```
let parseURL = "http://192.168.64.2/Project/test123.json"
```

The test123.json file contains:

```
    "videos": [
    {
        "url" : "(Any video url)"
    },

    {
        "url" : "(Any video url)"
    }
```

Now, my app now shows 2 video's. If I add a 3rd url, I need to restart the simulator in order to see the 3rd video.

I want to reload/refresh the url every 10 minutes so that when changes happen in my test123.json it will be visible in the simulator without having to restart the simulator. (hope this makes everything a bit more clear)

Comment: Can you show your code? It is not clear where the problem is from describing it.

Comment: I updated my comment. Hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to refresh every 10 minutes, then use timer.scheduledTimer. But a better approach would be to use silent push notifications so your server can tell your app when new content is available.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the silent push notifications. About the timer.scheduledTimer, how would I approach this? I created a timer where my selector would be de parsedURL, but that does nothing. (5 second is for testing)
jsonReloadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(getJsonFromUrl), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: @Anna_JB Does `does nothing` mean it wasn’t called? Do you check with breakpoint or print statements?